# Send PUT request to Laravel Controller via JavaScript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, laravel, fetch-api

I want to pass data to my laravel controller to save them in database. Here is my code..

HTML meta Tag..

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

javascript code Block..

```
    const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
    url = '/customer/create';

    fetch(url,{
        method: 'PUT',
        credentials: 'omit',
        mode: 'same-origin',
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "X-CSRF-Token": token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({name: 'Customer Name'})
    });
```

Router code block...

```
Route::put('/customer/create', [
'uses' => 'CustomerController@createNew',
'as' => 'customer.create'
]);
```

Controller code block (Just for testing)...

```
public function createNew(Request $request){

    return $request;
}
```

But it Giving me this error ar chrome console..

```
PUT http://uran.test/customer/create 419 (unknown status)
```

or Should I use Jquery AJAX (But I love to Use Vanilla JS for this App).

Comment: Try this: `document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');` check if the token is set correctly. And make sure it's in the head of the page.

Comment: Its also not working. when i check for if the token variable is set correctly by `console.log(token)`. It output to the console `yqcc7X5CREcZvgiRZG0EoHsNPSFQ1oNCMRwgDNro`

Comment: What if you comment out `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` in `Http/Kernel.php` ? Does it then work?

Comment: After commented that line, then there is no errors. but nothing happens after pressing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change X-CSRF-Token to X-CSRF-TOKEN

Comment: maybe try add this 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' to headers

Comment: Try axios or jquery ajax if the error will be same.